# How to remove light and camera in blender 2.82a

Tags: modeling

I am learning blender and new to this forum and this is my fist post as well. I am struggling to sort the below mentioned problem of achieving the same result in Material Preview without light and camera. Please note : The first two screenshots are of the reference video that I am following and the person is using Blender 2.80 whereas mine is 2.82a

The below screenshot shows that the person is modeling without a light and yet his objects doesn't looks black in Material Preview mode.
**Below image shows outliner with no Camera or Light :**
[image: Below image shows outliner with no Camera or Light]

The Ref image shows his viewport in Material Preview :
[image]

Unlike mine, where the objects looks completely black in Material Preview when I delete light manually :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

While you are still in *Material Preview* mode, go to the top-right of your viewport and select the *Shading* dropdown. Under it is a *Lighting* section. Look for 
**Scene World** and see if it is checked. If it is, uncheck it. With it checked, the actual lighting in the scene is used in Material Shading.

[image]

Comment: I did as advised by you but it didn't made any difference..

Answer (score 0):

I unchecked the 'Scene World' as suggested by R-800.  I then got three additional options: Rotation, Strength, Background.  I increased Strength to about 1.000 to get my object to show-up without a light. It was otherwise completely blacked-out.

[image]

Comment: Not working in my case.. Maybe it has something to do with my GPU as blender is not supporting it. By the way I'm using nvidia 9600gt.. released way back in 2009.